# Add row to html table below the selected row when previous row has rowspan

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have the following code to add rows to a table using a context menu plugin so you can right click the cell you want to add the row below.

```
(function($){
    function scanTable( $table ) {
        var m = [];
        $table.children( "tr" ).each( function( y, row ) {
            $( row ).children( "td, th" ).each( function( x, cell ) {
                var $cell = $( cell ),
                    cspan = $cell.attr( "colspan" ) | 0,
                    rspan = $cell.attr( "rowspan" ) | 0,
                    tx, ty;
                cspan = cspan ? cspan : 1;
                rspan = rspan ? rspan : 1;
                for( ; m[y] && m[y][x]; ++x );  //skip already occupied cells in current row
                for( tx = x; tx < x + cspan; ++tx ) {  //mark matrix elements occupied by current cell with true
                    for( ty = y; ty < y + rspan; ++ty ) {
                        if( !m[ty] ) {  //fill missing rows
                            m[ty] = [];
                        }
                        m[ty][tx] = true;
                    }
                }
                var pos = { top: y, left: x };
                $cell.data( "cellPos", pos );
            } );
        } );
    };

    /* plugin */
    $.fn.cellPos = function( rescan ) {
        var $cell = this.first(),
            pos = $cell.data( "cellPos" );
        if( !pos || rescan ) {
            var $table = $cell.closest( "table, thead, tbody, tfoot" );
            scanTable( $table );
        }
        pos = $cell.data( "cellPos" );
        return pos;
    }
})(jQuery);

appendMe();

function appendMe() {
    $('table.test td').find("em").remove()
    $('table.test td').removeAttr("realCellEq").append(function(){
        return "<em> " + $(this).cellPos().left + "</em>"
    }).attr("realCellEq", function() {
        return $(this).cellPos().left
    });
}

$(function () {
    $.contextMenu({
        selector: 'table.test td',
        items: {
            "addRowBelow": {
                name: "Add Row Below",
                callback: function (key, options) {
                    $(this).parents("tr").after("<tr class='freshAdd'></tr>");
                    $(this).parents("tr").find("td").each( function() {
                        var thisRowSpan = ($(this).attr("rowspan")) ? $(this).attr("rowspan") : 1;
                        if(thisRowSpan > 1) {
                            $(this).attr("rowspan", (parseInt($(this).attr("rowspan"),10)+1));
                        } else {
                            $(this).clone().appendTo("tr.freshAdd");
                        }
                    });
                    $("tr.freshAdd").find("td").html("");
                    $("tr.freshAdd").removeClass("freshAdd");
                    appendMe(); 
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The trouble is i can't work out what I need to do to take into consideration rowspans.

Here's a jsfiddle to explain what I mean.

http://jsfiddle.net/many_tentacles/sqjak/1/

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are not able to add a fresh cell, using the the freshly added cells is , those freshly added cells contain a class called `context-menu-active` which prohibits the functions you have written to add the cells.

You need to do a small change inside `callback` like :

```
$(".context-menu-active").removeClass('context-menu-active');
```

This removes the class from any freshly added cell and hence it becomes usable again.

**Look at the updated fiddle :**  http://jsfiddle.net/Q5PgG/

Comment: Thanks, this has answered another problem I was looking to solve but not the one I've tried to explain in this question. In my example please try adding a row below the second row and see what happens...

Answer (score 0):

Your `parents("tr")` was not targeting previous parents so i have added `prev()` each() function , you can do it this way:

```
$(this).parent("tr").after("<tr class='freshAdd'></tr>");
$(this).parent("tr").prev().find("td").each( function() {
var thisRowSpan = ($(this).attr("rowspan")) ? $(this).attr("rowspan") : 1;
   if(thisRowSpan > 1) {
      $(this).attr("rowspan", (parseInt($(this).attr("rowspan"),10)+1));
    }
})
$(this).parent("tr").find("td").each( function() {
   var thisRowSpan = ($(this).attr("rowspan")) ? $(this).attr("rowspan") : 1;
   if(thisRowSpan > 1) {
   $(this).attr("rowspan", (parseInt($(this).attr("rowspan"),10)+1));
   } else {
   $(this).clone().appendTo("tr.freshAdd");
   }
```

Working demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sqjak/6/)

Comment: Almost there.... but if you now add a row after the last row (where there is no problem with rowspans) it breaks in a different way. Getting there though!

Comment: @Tom using prev() instead of prevAll() solves the problem, but this will break if you have rowspan more than 2, then in that case using a count variable and going in reverse could solve the problem

Comment: I'd thought this would be the solution, but I'm just not sure how to do it! Can't get my head around it!